# Hibernate change property instance by id

Tags: java, hibernate

Say we have a User class with UserType property defined:

```
private UserType userType;
```

Is it possible to set this property using only ID of needed UserType?  Something like

```
public void setUserTypeById(Long id){
   this.userType.setId(id); 
}
```

But this one will only change the `id` property of assigned UserType instance, while I need to change it to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it would be possible, if you had access to a [session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) or to a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) in your `User` class. Then you could just retrieve then `UserType` corresponding to the given ID and set it.

But I do not recommend this. I think it is better to clearly separate the domain classes (`User`, `UserType`) from the persistence classes (DAOs or session). Better create a service class (`UserService` for instance) that has a method `setUserType(User user, int typeId)` which takes care of this.

Comment: Hmm, yes, it could be achieved by querying a DB for a UserType instance to set, but I thought there could be a more ORM-way.. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, there is no way to do this in ORM-way, as appears, so I've used an HQL-requests in setter methods to change ids. So i'm marking this  answer, thanks!